# wamp server not workning when uncomment "Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"

Tags: apache, xampp, wamp, virtualhost

I needed to run virtual server and I uncommented Include "conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" As soon as i did that and restarted Wamp, it gives me "The requested URL / was not found on this server" Error. When I add the comment again it works.

I even tried editing drivers and adding all the necessary steps to have a virtual host.

Server configuration 
Windows 10.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Contents of the httpd-vhosts.conf file:-

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
ServerName dummy-host.example.com
ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help with your configuration, if you do not post it inside the question?

Comment: Please read the last line. Also I did not have to add anything to the vttpd-vhosts.conf. error gives even before adding anything to that file.

Comment: I am not interested if you added anything to that file. We need to see the contents. So that we can tell you what causes the issue. You see: we are good, but we are not _that_ good that we can somehow magically _guess_ what is in that file on your system. And no, just because you say that you installed some distribution of the apache http server on some MS-Windows system does _also_ not tell us the contents of that file.

Comment: Contents of which file are you interested in? httpd.conf file is a fresh one and I  only uncommented above mentioned line. I'am bit new to wamp so I really dnt have an idea of what information you need other than details I've added here.

Comment: Obviously the contents of the file `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`, since that content apparently causes the issues as soon as it gets included.

Comment: Added it to the question. Please check.

Comment: Thanks. I added an answer. Might not be final, but I assume that this at least brings you closer to solving your issue.

Comment: Check out this post. What is in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file is demo example code. Remove it all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for adding the contents of the configuration file to the question. Given that the situation looks like that: two virtual hosts are defined in there, the first will be treated as "default host", so that hosts configuration will is relevant for all incoming requests that can *not* be matched on a specific defined http host.

That default host defines the DocumentRoot as: `c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com`. So if you get the mentioned error message then most likely there is no content defined in that folder...

Comment: yeah this helped me. deleted first virtual hosts and added 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
</VirtualHost>
the problem solved.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Have fun!